# I'm experiencing loss of events in my modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a hover effect that is used on elements inside of a modal window (the modal window appears on the click of a link).  When you hover over the elements the first time, everything works great, however, if you close the modal window and then reopen it, the hover effect becomes glitchy (as in it works only sometimes, but most of time the effect is lost).

Here's my JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function modalFunc() {

        var mapModal = $('#map-modal');
        var closeModal = $('<span/>', {
            'class': 'close-modal',
            'text': 'X',
            'click': function() { mapModal.fadeOut(); }
        });

        function svgLoader() {
            var repFills = mapModal.find('path[fill=#00F71A]');
            var repBlanks = mapModal.find('path[fill=#00B609]');
            var stateModal = $('.state-modal');

            function hoverFunc() {
                var state = this.getAttribute('class');
                var qy = '.' + state + '.state-modal'; // jQuery selector
                this.setAttribute('stroke-width', 2);
                $(qy).appendTo(mapModal).fadeIn(200);
            }

            function unhoverFunc() {
                var state = this.getAttribute('class');
                var qy = '.' + state + '.state-modal';
                this.setAttribute('stroke-width', 0.5);
                stateModal.hide();
            }

            mapModal.prepend(closeModal).fadeIn();

            repFills.on('mouseover', hoverFunc).on('mouseout', unhoverFunc);

            repBlanks.on('mouseover', function() {
                this.setAttribute('stroke-width', 2);
               $('.state-modal.los-angeles').appendTo(mapModal).fadeIn(200);
            }).on('mouseout', function() {
                this.setAttribute('stroke-width', 0.5);
            });

        }

        mapModal.fadeIn().load('../images/namap600.svg', svgLoader);
    }

    $('#namerica').on('click', modalFunc);

});
```

I know I've experienced this problem before, and when using the $.load method with an .on('click') method requires you to pass the element as the second argument in the click method (.on('click', element, function()...) so as not to lose any functionality, however that is not working in this case.  If anyone can see the error in this code I would greatly appreciate a reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create the modal in jQuery and then [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it when you are done.

```
var closeModal = $('<span/>', {
    'class': 'close-modal',
    'text': 'X',
    'click': function() { mapModal.fadeOut().remove(); }
});
```

Comment: Actually, the mapModal is an element that is on the page that I'm querying... there's only one modal, but several other popups inside of that modal.  I'm going to try your suggestion for removing the modal when I'm done with it.

Comment: Ok, I created the modal using jQuery instead and then inserted it into the page, and now my events are good, so your suggestion helped me fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'll change the answer to suggest that, as the first part of my answer was a misread of your code.